# Spring Boot and custom shell commands

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line-interface

On the Spring manual (here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/html/dev-shell.html), there is info about `@CliCommand` annotation, as well as examples on how to write own shell commands and to test them. 
Unfortunately I could not find any info about how to exactly run custom created cli command from command line, on Spring Boot project. How can I run them?

Comment: There is no overlap between Spring Boot and Spring Shell (by design). What is it you need exactly? If you want to run custom code from an OS shell using Spring Boot, maybe the Spring Boot CLI would be a decent solution.

Comment: Example usage - having job offers application made in spring boot, sometimes I would like to ssh to server and run command that will mark offers as expired using ids provided as arguments.

Comment: That's a remote access use case. Should be covered by CRaSH (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-extending-the-remote-shell).

Comment: Or if you prefer JMX/HTTP just add a custom Endpoint.

Comment: Did not know about CRaSH, it looks amazing, thanks!